# read function: copying buffer to another char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm new to C and am trying to use the read function.  I want to take what's in the buffer (tempChar) and put it in another char array (str).  This is so I can run the read function again and add on to str later (because tempChar will be rewritten by the 2nd read function).  Like this:

```
char tempChar;
read(0, &tempChar, 10);

char *str;
str= (char*) malloc(10);
memcpy(str, &tempChar, fileSize); /*I'm doing something wrong here*/
```

All this so I can rerun:

```
read(0,&tempChar, 1);
str= realloc(str, 11);
str[10]=tempChar;
```

It compiles fine, but it gives me a segmentation fault when I actually try to run it.

Any ideas?  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have enough storage to store the 10 characters you are reading

you declared

```
char tempChar
```

which can hold 1 character.

Instead declare tempChar as

```
char tempChar[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char tempChar;
read(0, &tempChar, 10);
```

You are reading 10 characters from the file into memory only the size of a single char.
`char tempChar` only reserves memory for a single character, &tempChar points to this single byte of memory.

```
char *str;
str= (char*) malloc(10);

// why not now do ?
read(0, str, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char tempChar;
```

Only allocates 1 byte. So you can only hold there 1 char. When you `memcpy()` you request to copy 10 bytes, which do not exist. Hence you read memory you should not causing Undefined Behaviour (which gives you the SegFault).

You should do something like you did with `malloc()` for str or declare a local array like `char chatTemp[10]`. Note: `malloc()` does not require a cast in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read twice and put the results next to each other in the same buffer, you don't need a temporary buffer for that: you can use pointer arithmetic to tell `read` to use the second half of the original buffer.  Like so:

```
char buf[10];
ssize_t nread = read(0, buf, 5);
if (nread < 0)
    error();
else
{
    nread = read(0, buf + nread, sizeof buf - nread);
    if (nread < 0)
        error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a file descriptor as a first parameter to read function.. Also you need to allocate `char * buffer` instead of `char tempChar;`

[Check sample usage](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/pread.htm)

Comment: Zero is a file descriptor: by convention, it is the file descriptor underlying `stdin`.